# How do you change the color of the black banner bar?

Tags: xpages

I'd like to match one of the colors in my companies logo, but I'm just not sure what it is I need to change.  There are at least 4 div there.  Which one do I change? or Do I change all of them?  Is there someplace where I can lookup what needs to be changed?

Comment: Always use Firefox firebug or Chrome's developer tools to find the right class or id. it is really easy and you can change the style and see the result in real time

Comment: Please remember to flag your question answered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please take a look at this website: [Oneui v2.1 documentation](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/2.1/docPublic/index.htm). In the components tree you wil find the 'banner' component. This is the control you need to update/change.

The default implementation has the following styling:

```
.lotusBanner {
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #525252 0%, #000000 100%);
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

You should change the background-color and the background-image.  Best would be to create a new theme which extends the default oneuiv2.1 theme and add your own css to it which overides the defaults:

```
<theme extends="oneuiv2.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="platform:/plugin/com.ibm.designer.domino.stylekits/schema/stylekit.xsd" >
    <!-- 
        Use this pattern to include resources (such as style sheets
        and JavaScript files that are used by this theme.
    -->

    <resource>
        <content-type>text/css</content-type>
        <href>your.css</href>
    </resource>


    <!--
        Use this pattern to define property name/value pairs for controls
    -->
    <!--
    <control>
        <name>[Control Name]</name>
        <property>
            <name>[property Name]</name>
            <value>[property Value]</value>
        </property>
    </control>
    -->
</theme>
```